# mysql query based on result from one

Tags: mysql

This will probably be easy for allot of you guru's.

I am trying to get * from two tables.

First table i can match with a user_id. structure is as follows:

```
table name: order_new

id | service_id | user_id | total_price | total_price_tax | orderstatus | notes | orderdate



table name 2: order_new_items

id | id_order | name | qty | price
```

The first table ( order_new ) i can get by using the session id. that first table has a row called "id". That id has items in table 2 ( order_new_items ) under the row of "id_order".

Im not sure on how to join the two and pull all data from both tables matching id from first table and id_order from second table

Comment: `select *
from order_new o
join order_new_items i on i.id_order = o.id
where service_id = $yourServiceId`

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: The question is tagged MySQL and OP is asking for a MySQL query.

Comment: @juergend My apologies. It was a foolish question.

Comment: Thank you very much Refugnic Eternium! I was able to get it working based on your answer. Just chaning the service_id to user_id

select * from order_new o join order_new_items i on i.id_order = o.id where user_id = 1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL-Only:

```
SELECT * FROM order_new o, order_new_items i WHERE user_id = '7' AND o.id_order = i.id;
```

I'm assuming, that `id` from order_new is the primary key for the table, while `id_order` is the foreign key for the 1:n relationship.

To be noted, the 7 is an example of course and needs to be substituted with whatever value you're looking for.

According to comments, I'm answering another question:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_new WHERE user_id = 7");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //store order information
    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_new_items WHERE id_order = $row[id]");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2)) {
        //store further information
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a new issue :/     Not sure if this can be resolved from the query itself.

Because im pulling this data in a php array loop, its displaying the orders 4 times because 4 items exist in the other table..

is there a way to limit certain rows to 1 x in the query?

Comment: @Elgoots First off: Consider accepting an answer, once your actual question is answered. It shows your appreciation the best :)

Comment: @Elgoots Regarding your issue...I'm afraid I don't fully understand the problem. You have four entries in your PHP array and among them is the same order id multiple times?

Comment: Sorry it had a time frame on accepting an answer.

This image will help with my issue: http://www.freweb.com.au/example.jpg

So as you can see, if i pull that data from mysql and list it in a table. it repeats those highlited rows. i only wanted those highlighted rows spat out once IF there is more than 1 result in the other table. I hope that makes better sense?

Comment: @Elgoots It does. However I don't think you can do this with one query alone. What you CAN do though is a two-step query. I'll amend my answer (better formatting). Give me a few moments.

Comment: thank you for taking your time in helping me. Im still learning.
does the same thing   :/
http://www.freweb.com.au/example2.jpg  thats what it looks like on the webpage. Because there are 3 items its repeating the price, date, price and status etc.

Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/RFG5CFwm

Comment: @Elgoots Everyone needs to start at some point and I'm only a novice myself. That said, I need to ask one question: Do you want to display ALL results in your table or do you only want to display the FIRST one?

Comment: i was able to fix this issue in the loop by changing that last query to: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM nfw_order_new_items WHERE id_order = '$row[id]'

Comment: @Elgoots I see. Well, that's one way to go about it, to be sure. As an alternative, I would've put it into an array (PHP side) keyed to the order_id and displayed it like that. Good to know you were able to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM order_new, order_new_items where order_new.id = order_new_items.id and order_new.id = 4711
```

This will retrieve all rows where an ID exists in bot tables. It will **not** retrieve rows from table `order_new` when there are no corresponding rows in `order_new_items` (i.e. empty order)

To achieve this, you need to use:

```
 SELECT * FROM order_new
 LEFT JOIN order_new_items on order_new.id = order_new_items.id
 where order_new.id = 4711
```

probably you need to list columns explicitly instead of `*`

Comment: Refugnic was able to get it working grabbing all data from both tables with his reply.

Also thank you for posting your answer too. Appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will fetch you data from both tables based on conditon.

```
SELECT a*, b.id, b.name, b.qty, b.price FROM order_new a 
INNER JOIN order_new_items b on b.id_order = a.id
WHERE a.id = 100
```